# how to do java installation in Linux(Ubuntu)

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I want to build Android kk 4.4 and I followed google's instructions but it keeps give me a Java 1.6.0_24 version:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

I tried this:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

But I couldn't get the 1.6.0_26 version and I need it in order to build the full android.

How can I install the needed version using `apt-get`?!

Comment: I don't think such a strict restriction would be in place for android. **Please let us know a link of it.** If not working with 1.6.0_24, you better try `$ sudo apt-get install sun-java7-jdk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link you have provided above there is not mention about version of java. Also, the installation steps are direct.

Anyway to just specify an exact version of a package using apt-get you could do(apache2 installation example)

```
sudo apt-get install apache2=2.2.20-1ubuntu1
```

go through this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version)

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** Check to see if your Ubuntu Linux operating system architecture is 32-bit or 64-bit, open up a terminal and run the following command below.

```
file /sbin/init
```

**Note:** the bit version of your Ubuntu Linux operating system architecture it will display whether it is 32-bit or 64-bit.

---

**Step 2:** Check if you have Java installed on your system. To do this, you will have to run the Java version command from terminal.

Open up a terminal and enter the following command:

```
java -version
```

If you have OpenJDK installed on your system it may look like this:

```
java version "1.7.0_15"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10pre) (7b15~pre1-0lucid1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

If you have OpenJDK installed on your system, you have the wrong vendor version of Java installed for this exercise.

---

**Step 3:** Completely remove the OpenJDK/JRE from your system and create a directory to hold your Oracle Java JDK/JRE binaries. This will prevent system conflicts and confusion between different vendor versions of Java. For example, if you have the OpenJDK/JRE installed on your system, you can remove it by typing the following at the command line:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*
```

This command will completely remove OpenJDK/JRE from your system

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/java
```

This command will create a directory to hold your Oracle Java JDK and JRE binaries.

---

**Step 4:** [Download the Oracle Java JDK/JRE for Linux.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)Make sure you select the correct compressed binaries for your system architecture 32-bit or 64-bit (which end in tar.gz).

- For example, if you are on Ubuntu Linux 32-bit operating system download 32-bit Oracle Java binaries.
- For example, if you are on Ubuntu Linux 64-bit operating system download 64-bit Oracle Java binaries.
- **Important Information:** 64-bit Oracle Java binaries do not work on 32-bit Ubuntu Linux operating systems, you will receive multiple system error messages, if you attempt to install 64-bit Oracle Java on 32-bit Ubuntu Linux.

---

**Step 5:** Copy the Oracle Java binaries into the /usr/local/java directory. In most cases, the Oracle Java binaries are downloaded to:

```
/home/"your_user_name"/Downloads
```

**32-bit Oracle Java on 32-bit Ubuntu Linux installation instructions:**

```
cd /home/"your_user_name"/Downloads

sudo cp -r jdk-7u45-linux-i586.tar.gz /usr/local/java

sudo cp -r jre-7u45-linux-i586.tar.gz /usr/local/java

cd /usr/local/java
```

**64-bit Oracle Java on 64-bit Ubuntu Linux installation instructions:**

```
cd /home/"your_user_name"/Downloads

sudo cp -r jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/java

sudo cp -r jre-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/java

cd /usr/local/java
```

---

**Step 6:** Unpack the compressed Java binaries, in the directory **/usr/local/java**

**32-bit Oracle Java on 32-bit Ubuntu Linux installation instructions:**

```
sudo tar xvzf jdk-7u45-linux-i586.tar.gz
sudo tar xvzf jre-7u45-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

**64-bit Oracle Java on 64-bit Ubuntu Linux installation instructions:**

```
sudo tar xvzf jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo tar xvzf jre-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

---

**Step 7:** Double-check your directories. At this point, you should have two uncompressed binary directories in /usr/local/java for the Java JDK/JRE listed as:

```
ls -a
```

Output should be

- jdk1.7.0_45
- jre1.7.0_45

---

**Step 8:** Edit the system PATH file **/etc/profile** and add the following system variables to your system path. Use nano, gedit or any other text editor, as root, open up /etc/profile.

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
(or)
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

---

**Step 9:** Scroll down to the end of the file using your arrow keys and add the following lines below to the end of your **/etc/profile** file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_45
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Save the file

---

**Step 10:** Inform your Ubuntu Linux system where your Oracle Java JDK/JRE is located. This will tell the system that the new Oracle Java version is available for use.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_45/bin/java" 1
```

this command notifies the system that Oracle Java JRE is available for use

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javac" 1
```

this command notifies the system that Oracle Java JDK is available for use

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_45/bin/javaws" 1
```

this command notifies the system that Oracle Java Web start is available for use

---

**Step 11:** Inform your Ubuntu Linux system that Oracle Java JDK/JRE must be the default Java.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_45/bin/java
```

this command will set the java runtime environment for the system

```
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javac
```

this command will set the javac compiler for the system

```
sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_45/bin/javaws
```

this command will set Java Web start for the system

---

**Step 12:** Reload your system wide PATH /etc/profile by typing the following command:

```
./etc/profile
```

**Note:** your system-wide PATH /etc/profile file will reload after reboot of your Ubuntu Linux system.

---

**Step 13:** A successful installation of Oracle Java will display:

> **for 32-bit**

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

javac -version
javac 1.7.0_45
```

> **for 64-bit**

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

javac -version
javac 1.7.0_45
```

> **Congratulations, you just installed Oracle Java on your Linux system.**
>   Now reboot your Ubuntu Linux system. Afterwards, your system will be
>   fully configured for running and developing Java programs

Answer (score 1):

I always use the Oracle JDK Download site.  This allows you to get any version of [Java 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) you want, or any version back to Java 1.1.

BTW I would consider upgrading from ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 if not 13.10.

Comment: IMO Excellent suggestions. +1.